# How to call the bootstrap files without using CDN?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have downloaded the bootstrap folder from the site. And i have a folder named demoproject on my desktop and in that the bootstrap folder is present. How should i call these bootstrap files without using CDN so it runs without internet connection.

Comment: Check this: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make sure that the lines in your HTML file that look like this:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

and

```
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

are pointing to your local files (similar to shown above) and not to the CDN.

Comment: Thank for your reply anson vandoren bootstrap.min.css file is working  but my bootstrap.min.js file is not running its giving error Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery(anonymous function) @ bootstrap.min.js:6. the path i gave is <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: Check for a line in your HTML that looks like `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>` (which loads jQuery from Google). If you don't have it, you'll need to add it. If you want to load it locally instead of from Google, just download it like you did with Bootstrap and change the path to your local path.

Comment: from where will i get that file can you send me the link??

Comment: Try Googling "download jQuery" and see what happens

Comment: still getting the same error i have dowloaded compressed jquery-1.11.3.min.js file and path i gave is <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

Comment: The order that you call the scripts is important. You should load jQuery on the line above Bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

**Bootstrap with CDN**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**Bootstrap with out CDN**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="foldername/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="foldername/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you download the file, you can include **bootstrap.min.css** file in the *<head>* and **bootstrap.min.js** in *<body>*. Even if you are using the downloaded bootstrap file, you have to include **jquery.min.js** and **popper.min.js** before loading **bootstrap.min.js**